# Ajax call without URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to hide a dropdown list when user click radio button. For this am going to use AJAX instead of JS. Here, my code's :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        element.style.display = "";
        **element.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;**
     }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("POST","**URL**",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}    
</script>
```

Above element.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText & URL should i want to use ? there's no reason to pass ajax call to some other page. i done my work here. without URL script not worked. plz sort out me from this issue.

Comment: You mean to say ajax is not JS? And what do you mean by ajax without url? If you are not hitting any server why do need ajax?

Comment: You don't make a lick of sense... Please format your entry properly, and try making sentences that actually mean something...

Comment: Did you know that Ajax was originally an acronym meaning Asynchronous Javascript And XML? So you literally cannot use Ajax without Javascript. It might be useful to look over some introductory tutorials on Javascript and Ajax to understand the terms. I think the easiest way to do what you are describing would be to use Javascript through JQuery ( a Javascript library you can freely use ), which would probably only take a line or two of code.

Comment: hey, dont understand wrongly.. JS is client side script. i want to do all the stuffs at server side. The task is very simple want to hide dropdown list. if i'm not making sense. Give your idea how to hide with ajax call.

Comment: @siva:  Why you are saying this has to be done with Ajax call? You can't hide a control in a page with Ajax call itself.. First of all you need to understand that Ajax call can be made from javascript. and ajax call is used to call server side code.

Comment: @mahesh yes i know that both Ajax and JS were tightly coupled. Now i understood cant hide the controls which are presnt in the page. challenged myself want to do at serverside also the page should not get reload.Is anyother way possible to do ? thanks

Comment: @siva: i am asking again why do you want to do it in server side? since its just of hiding a dropdownlist when a radio button is clicked. This can be done in client side with jquery/javascript.. i am not sure why you go for server side coding..

Comment: @mahesh Initially, i done with javascript only.. i tried IE5 and lower version browser. that time i know about JS not support some of the old version browser. later i think about why cant we do all the stuffs at serverside. This the reason behind my Question.

Comment: in which language you are writing this..? .Net ?

Comment: nope.. JSP & strtus 1.2 framework.

Comment: k .. You can use Jquery .. to do it..

Answer (score 0):

How about his,

```
function loadXMLDoc()   // your suitable method name
{

        var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        element.style.display = "";
}
```

You dont need an ajax call ;)

Comment: i too done same code. Thing is it pure javascript. same thing should happen through ajax call.

Comment: If its server side then you need a server side language to do it. Something like PHP or JSP and it will require a page reload and not work through ajax. I think you are missing the point of ajax here.